# How do I stop my links from wrapping inside a DIV?

Tags: html, css

I have six links inside a 100% width DIV.

How can I stop my links from stacking on top of each other, moving, down, and disappearing as I shrink the size of my browser?  I would like to have them remain inside the horizontal div.

Here is my code:

```css
.nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 84px;
  float: left;
  background: #333;
}

.logo {
  width: 317px;
  height: 84px;
  float: left;
  background: url('img/lifesign.png');
}

.navlink {
  height: 84px;
  font-family: 'open_sansbold';
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 84px;
  padding-left: 22px;
  padding-right: 22px;
  float: right;
  font-size: 80%
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <a href="contact.htm" class="navlink">CONTACT</a>
  <a href="contact.htm" class="navlink">GET INVOLVED</a>
  <a href="contact.htm" class="navlink">Q+A</a>
  <a href="contact.htm" class="navlink">HOW IT WORKS</a>
  <a href="contact.htm" class="navlink">WHO WE ARE</a>
  <a class="logo" href="home.htm"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set a `min-width` on your `.nav` class.

```
.nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 84px;
    float: left;
    background: #333;

    min-width: 960px; /* or whatever width you need */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the ideal here would be to create a div of fixed width (id of 'page' below) to contain your nav and other page elements. I also took the liberty of cleaning up some of the structure of the nav itself, as well as some of the more unnecessary rules. I think a list is ideal here. You may want to reverse the order of it since you are floating right but otherwise it works great.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        body { text-align: center; }
        #container { width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; }
        #nav { overflow: hidden; list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; background: #333; }
        #nav li { float: right; }
        #nav li.logo { float: left; }
        #nav li a { display: block; padding: 0px 22px; color:#FFF; background: #333; text-align:center; line-height:84px; font-family: 'open_sansbold'; font-size:80%; }
        #nav li.logo a { width: 317px; height: 84px; background:url('img/lifesign.png') red; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <ul id="nav">
                <li class="logo"><a href="home.htm"></a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.htm">CONTACT</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.htm">GET INVOLVED</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.htm">Q+A</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.htm">HOW IT WORKS</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.htm">WHO WE ARE</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="main">
                <!-- page content here -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also using 'margin: 0 auto;' keeps the fixed-width 'container' div centered on the page.